# Enqueue different stylesheets using IE conditionals

Tags: themes

I want to load a different css for IE 9 below 
so I have two files :
- style.css
- ie.css

I used this code :

```
<!--[if !IE]> --> style.css <!-- <![endif]-->
```

and used this for IE

```
<!--[if IE]>  ie.css <![endif]-->
```

but I dont know how to use this condition to use **style.css** for both non-IE and IE9

Comment: This question is **not a duplicate** of the referenced question. This question deals with IE conditionals for **CSS**, and the other question deals with loading **template files** based on UA.

Comment: Okay, I re-opened it. But I think it is not on topic here, and is prepared so bad it shouldn't be asked anywhere in the SE network without further improvements.
@Dave Try researching first. There are thousands of articles about this topic.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to handle this one. I also think it's off-topic, but it can be answered in a WordPress-specific manner, if it addresses *enqueueing* stylesheets based on IE conditionals.

Comment: Thank you for re-opening this topic and changing the topic title.

Answer (score 3):

While [basic use of CSS IE conditionals](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) is **off-topic** for WPSE, WordPress *does* include a method for *enqueueing* stylesheets conditionally, based on CSS IE conditionals.

First, you need to use the correct conditionals:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>  ie.css <![endif]-->
```

Second, you should [*enqueue* this stylesheet properly](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style), in `functions.php`, via callback hooked into `wp_enqueue_scripts`:

```
<?php
function wpse48581_enqueue_ie_css() {
    // Register stylesheet
    wp_register_style( 'wpse45851-ie', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie.css' );
    // Apply IE conditionals
    $GLOBALS['wp_styles']->add_data( 'wpse45851-ie', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
    // Enqueue stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse45851-ie' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse48581_enqueue_ie_css' );
?>
```

#### Edit

Based on this comment:

> But I only want to use ie.css on IE less than IE9 and style.css for IE9 and non-IE browser

This is actually a *non-standard* way of defining stylesheets for IE support, because it completely circumvents the **cascading** part of CSS. Nevertheless, it is entirely possible. Simply use the above method to enqueue `style.css` also, using the appropriate conditionals. For example, this may not be the *best* approach, but it will work:

```
<?php
function wpse48581_enqueue_ie_css() {
    // Register and enqueue lt IE9 stylesheet
    wp_register_style( 'wpse45851-ie', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie.css' );
    $GLOBALS['wp_styles']->add_data( 'wpse45851-ie', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse45851-ie' );
    // Register and enqueue IE9 stylesheet
    wp_register_style( 'wpse45851-ie9', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    $GLOBALS['wp_styles']->add_data( 'wpse45851-ie9', 'conditional', 'IE 9' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse45851-ie9' );
    // Register and enqueue default stylesheet
    // Note that we use the SAME style.css as above
    wp_register_style( 'wpse45851-default', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    $GLOBALS['wp_styles']->add_data( 'wpse45851-default', 'conditional', '!IE' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse45851-default' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse48581_enqueue_ie_css' );
?>
```

**Caveat**: this will *work*, but I **strongly recommend** that you reconsider your approach to your IE-specific style declarations. Your life will be *much* easier if you always use your default stylesheet, and then take advantage of the cascade to *override* the default, where necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the respond, I tried this , but the problem is that when the site is launched on a IE 8 the browser use style.css as well. But I only want to use ie.css on IE less than IE9 and style.css for IE9 and non-IE browser

Comment: See updated answer. I think you're taking the wrong approach, but it *can* be done.

Answer (score 0):

You don't load different CSS files, you create different classes. Add this function to your `functions.php`:

```
/**
 * HTML5 start tag + language attribute + conditional tags for IE Win
 *
 * @link   http://paulirish.com/?p=88
 * @param  bool $print
 * @return void|string
 */
function t5_htmlstart( $print = TRUE )
{
    $out       = '<!Doctype html>';
    $wpclasses = join( ' ', get_body_class() );
    $lang      = t5_get_language_attributes();
    $ies       = array (
        6 => 'lte6 lte7 lte8'
    ,   7 => 'lte7 lte8'
    ,   8 => 'lte8'
    ,   9 => ''
    );

    foreach ( $ies as $n => $class )
    {
        $out .= "<!--[if IE $n]><html $lang class='ie ie$n $class lte9 $wpclasses'><![endif]-->";
    }

    $out .= "<!--[if !IE]><!--><html $lang class='$wpclasses'><!--<![endif]-->";

    $print and print $out;
    return $out;
}

/**
 * Returns the language attributes.
 *
 * Unobstrusive copy from the core.
 * Requires WP 3.0+
 *
 * @param string $doctype The type of html document (xhtml|html).
 */
function t5_get_language_attributes( $doctype = 'html' )
{
    $output = is_rtl() ? 'dir="rtl"' : '';

    if ( $lang = get_bloginfo( 'language' ) )
    {
        $output .= ( ( get_option( 'html_type' ) != 'text/html'
            || $doctype == 'xhtml' )
            ? ' xml:' : '') . 'lang="' . $lang . '"';
    }

    return apply_filters( 'language_attributes', $output );
}
```

In your `header.php` you call this function where you want to see the Doctype:

```
<?php t5_htmlstart() ?>
```

Now, you can address each individual IE or groups of them in your stylesheet:

```
.lte8 #searchform div {
    height:             1.9em;
}
.ie7 .widget_search input {
    margin:             -1px 0;
    padding:            5px 5px;
}
.ie9 .widget_search input {
    margin-left:        -2px;
}
```

But the possibility to use this code in a WordPress theme doesn't make it magically on topic. I will regret this.

Comment: the problem is that I am creating a responsive wordpress theme and I did not noticed that my theme is not working on IE<IE9 - so I want to create a second style sheet called ie.css - but when ever the site is opened in IE it also grabs the styles from style.css -

Comment: @Dave See it as a good thing: You really don't want to duplicate your complete CSS, do you? Just overwrite the parts IE doesn't understand with specialized rules.