# Having issue with WordPress wp_enqueue_style

Tags: theme-development, themes, css, wp-enqueue-style

I am building a full design into `WordPress` for the first time and I am trying to load in stylesheets and script files but all I seem to be getting is the text output of the location.

What I have is below..

```
wp_enqueue_style('reset', bloginfo('template_url') . '/reset.css');
wp_enqueue_style('style', bloginfo('stylesheet_url'), array('reset'));
wp_enqueue_style('rhino', bloginfo('template_url') . '/rhinoslider-1.05.css', array('reset','style'));
```

Do I need to put this inside the `link` tags or something? I thought it would do it all itself; as what's the point loading it that way if it doesn't do it itself? I know it makes sure the same file isn't included twice or something, but if you have to include the link tags yourself and then WP decides not to include the file then you are left with blank link tags!?

I also tried putting the below in my themes `functions.php` file but got the same results.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mmw_new_theme_setup' );

function mmw_new_theme_setup() {

    /* Add theme support for post formats. */   
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats' );

    /* Add theme support for post thumbnails. */    
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

    /* Add theme support for automatic feed links. */   
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

    /* Add theme support for menus. */  
    add_theme_support( 'menus' );

    /* Load style files on the 'wp_enqueue_scripts' action hook. */
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mmw_new_load_styles' );

}

function mmw_new_load_styles() {

    $foo = bloginfo('template_url') . '/reset.css';
    $bar = bloginfo('template_url') . '/rhinoslider-1.05.css';

    wp_enqueue_style('reset', $foo);
    wp_enqueue_style('style', bloginfo('stylesheet_url'), array('reset'));
    wp_enqueue_style('rhino', $bar, array('reset','style'));

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found you using function `bloginfo()` which echo out the value, You should use [`get_bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) function to pass the value to varibales - `$foo, $bar` and to the function `wp_enqueue_style()`.

Comment: I changed it, but no change. Still getting the paths output as noted above.

Comment: OK, found it - use [`get_bloginfo()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) function to get the value.

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks so much for picking that up. One more question though, how do you manage this if you only need a certain style for IE and need to use the conditional tags? Do you need to load it via the header?

Comment: You've to manually add that into header.php, Or use  [This plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/php-browser-detection/) (Not tested)

Comment: How do you make sure it comes after other styles?

Comment: note that the `after_setup_theme` function is called during theme initialization(on each page-load). -- I'm sorry for sending you in wrong direction. (Also removed that from answer )

Comment: Ok, so I *can* call `wp_enqueue_scripts` from within `mmw_new_theme_setup` like I did above then?

Comment: Re: "*One more question though, how do you manage this if you only need a certain style for IE and need to use the conditional tags?*": Please put questions in your **original question**, or start a **new question**. Few people will find this follow up question, since it's buried in a comment.

Comment: The specific problem was indeed that you were using `bloginfo()`, which *echoes* its value, instead of `get_bloginfo()`, which *returns* its value. However, I would recommend using `get_template_directory_uri()` instead of `get_bloginfo( 'template_url' )`, since [the latter simply calls the former anyway](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L443).

Comment: Another note: I would pull this: `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mmw_new_load_styles' );` out of your Theme setup function, and just let it fire directly from `functions.php`.

Comment: And regarding IE conditionals: [there *is* a "WordPress" way to use `wp_enqueue_style()` with IE conditionals](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/48587/3966). (And there is an open Trac ticket to add the same thing to `wp_enqueue_script()` as well.)