# Replacing parent theme's IE-specific CSS

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-style

I'm trying to do exactly what was apparently achieved in [this discussion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65523/how-do-i-dequeue-a-parent-theme-css-file).

However, I'm finding that my IE-specific stylesheet's being loaded all the time!

My parent theme includes this in its functions.php:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'twentytwelve-ie', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie.css', array( 'twentytwelve-style' ), '20121010' );
```

And I'm adding this to my child theme's functions.php - which, if I understand correctly, should remove the parent version of ie.css and replace it with mine:

```
function PREFIX_remove_scripts() {
wp_dequeue_style( 'twentytwelve-ie' );

// Now register your styles and scripts here
wp_enqueue_style( 'treetop-ie', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/ie.css',     array( 'twentytwelve-style' ), '20121010' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'PREFIX_remove_scripts', 200 );
```

Well, my ie.css is loading, all right, but in *all* browsers.

What did i get wrong?

Thanks...
adam

Comment: Why are you changing the `priority` of `add_action()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enqueue different stylesheets using IE conditionals](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48581/enqueue-different-stylesheets-using-ie-conditionals)

Comment: You're just asking the wrong question. It should read what I've linked as duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for this, kaiser - I will have a good read of that linked discussion.

Comment: Chip, I think I am simply not 100% clear on the correct usage of `add_action()`, sadly. I'm trying to wrap my head around it 100%. But I'll see if perhaps this approach is rendered moot by the solutions in the linked discussion.

Comment: Had a look. Good stuff, and beyond that, it looks like the solution that I went for in the interim - simply adding ie-only styles to my main CSS file - worked out fine. WP is already adding a class of "ie" to the HTML tag when viewed in that browser thanks to built-in IE conditional code; I just made use of that already-in-place option and added some `html.ie body #myDivTag` type of rules at the end of my stylesheet. Perfecto!